# Can i use #id or .class with $(this) in jquery

Tags: jquery

Can i use like this in jquery 
    `$(this+"#id").html(...);`  or is ther any other method.
I had a such a situation to use like this. my code is given below

html code

```
<div id="box1">
<div ></div>
</div>
```

css code is

```
#box1  {  
width:300px;
height:200px;
border:1px solid #333;
}  
#box1 div
{
width:200px;
height:150px;
border:1px solid #999;
margin:auto;
margin-top:10px;

}
```

Jquery code is

```
$(document).ready(function()
              {
                  $("#box1").mouseenter(function()
         {

         $(this+"div").html("<p>Mouse entered</p>");

        });    });
```

See my code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/68Dgv)

Comment: Using reasonable, consistent code indentation will help you prevent bugs, and will help people help you when you have questions. All due respect, but that code block at the end of the question is just a complete disaster.

Answer (score 4):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#box1").mouseenter(function() {
         // $(this) references the #box1 element, and turns it into a jquery object
         // .find searches inside this DOM node for the new selector
         $(this).find("div").html("<p>Mouse entered</p>");
    });    
});
```

[.find method](http://api.jquery.com/find/) - searches inside the DOM element for a new selector.  Returns the matches as a jQuery object.

I reformatted your code to use the convention we use at work.  Notice the open curlies are on the same line, and then the matching close is dedented to its opening level.  There are quite a few "best practices" out there so try and find one and stick with it.  It will make reading, understanding, and debugging code much easier.

Answer (score 3):

You can [add context in your query](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context) like so:

```
$('selector', context)
```

So for yours use:

```
$('div', this)
```

You can also use the [find method](http://api.jquery.com/find/) like so:

```
$(this).find('div');
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#box1").mouseenter(function()
    {
      $("div", this).html("<p>Mouse entered</p>");
    });    
});
```

here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/68Dgv/1/)

Comment: @VladIoffe in your comment your quotes are misaligned.

Comment: thanks @ Brombomb. When you trying to select some elements inside of some this element this is one of the ways to it $("this_child_selector", this). There are plenty more, but for me it is clean and fast

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
 $(this).find("div").html("<p>Mouse entered</p>");
```